# Unable to stop consuming in Pika

Tags: python, python-3.x, pika

I am unable to return the data from the Pika since it `start_consuming` is not stopping. It prints the results but it does not return the output

```
def on_request(ch, method, props, body):
    directory =body

    print(directory.decode('utf-8'))
    response = parse(directory.decode('utf-8'))

    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                     routing_key=props.reply_to,
                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id = \
                                                         props.correlation_id),
                     body=str(response))
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
def start():
    print("hi")
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

    channel = connection.channel()


    channel.queue_declare(queue='rpc_queue')

    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=2)
    channel.basic_consume(queue='rpc_queue', on_message_callback=on_request)

    print(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests")
    channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 1):

By design `start_consuming` blocks forever. You will have to cancel the consumer in your `on_request` method.

You can also use [this method](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/blocking_consumer_generator.html) to consume messages which allows an `inactivity_timeout` to be set, where you could then cancel your consumer.

Finally, `SelectConnection` allows much more flexibility in interacting with Pika's I/O loop and is recommended when your requirements are more complex than what `BlockingConnection` supports.

Answer (score 1):

For a pika's BlockingConnection, you just need to shut it down with connection.close() within your callback function, under those conditions you need to stop consuming. Your program will then complete the callback function and continue after the channel.start_consuming() call without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Just use channel.stop_consuming()